# Delete every 3rd and 5th line except 15th line with Stream EDitor

Tags: sed

I need to delete every 3rd and 5th line except the 15th line in a text file using [sed](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html).
Has someone an idea?

Comment: Is this an interview question? :)

Answer (score 3):

Try next command. You will need the GNU version of `sed`:

```
sed '15 b ; 0~3 d ; 0~5 d' infile
```

First check if line is 15th: print and read next one. Otherwise, delete every 3rd line and every 5th line starting with first one.

Answer (score 2):

It's much easy if you use `awk`:

```
$ awk '(NR%3 && NR%5) || NR==15' input.txt
```

Comment: I think it should be (NR!=15), OQ said except 15th, not except every 15th.